# Скопировать часть текста из файла word в другой файл

Tags: c#, office, ms-word

Задача - есть достаточно массивный файл Word с некоторым количеством текста. Нужно просмотреть весь файл, найти слово, далее расширить область выделения вправо и влево от этого слова, и скопировать получившееся выделение в новый файл. Далее - повторить поиск для оставшейся части документа и выполнить копирование таким же способом в тот же новый файл. Казалось бы всё просто, но после того, как я один раз выделяю текст и копирую, то потом просто не могу восстановить range до состояния "оставшегося документа".

```
if (Frm2.checkBox4.Checked == true) 
{
    object unit = Word.WdUnits.wdStory;
    object extend = Word.WdMovementType.wdMove;
    Object Story = Word.WdUnits.wdStory;
    Object MoveRight = Word.WdMovementType.wdMove;


    Object begin_temple = 0;//для шаблона начало
    Object end_temple = worddocument_TEMPLE.Content.End;//для шаблона конец
    Object begin = Type.Missing;//для отчёта начало
    Object end = Type.Missing;//для отчёта конец
    Word.Range wordrange_TEMPLE = worddocument_TEMPLE.Range(ref begin_temple, ref end_temple);//присвоили диапазону область в документе-шаблоне. Здесь она равна ВСЕМУ документу

    worddocument = wordapp.Documents.Add(ref missObj, ref newTemplate, ref documentType, ref visible);//документ новый, с будущим результатом
    Word.Range wordrange = worddocument.Range(ref begin, ref end);//создали диапазон для работы с итоговым файлом
    object countStart = -250;
    object unitStart = Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter;
    object countEnd = 1500;
    object unitEnd = Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter;



    wordrange_TEMPLE.Find.ClearFormatting();
    wordrange_TEMPLE.Find.MatchWholeWord = true;
    wordrange_TEMPLE.Find.MatchCase = true;
    wordrange_TEMPLE.Find.Forward = true;
    wordrange_TEMPLE.Find.Text = "Группа";//маска для поиска
    filename_TOTAL = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
    filename_TOTAL += "Группа";

    wordrange_TEMPLE.Find.Execute(
            ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj,
            ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj,
            ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj);
    while (wordrange_TEMPLE.Find.Found)
    {
        //wordrange_TEMPLE.Select();//выделили то, что нашли
        wordrange_TEMPLE.MoveStart(ref unitStart, ref countStart);//переместили начальную позицию диапазона 
        wordrange_TEMPLE.MoveEnd(ref unitEnd, ref countEnd);//переместили конечную позицию диапазона 
        wordrange_TEMPLE.Select();//выделили текст между границами
        wordrange_TEMPLE.Copy();//скопировали всё информацию
        wordrange.Paste();//вставили в другой документ
        wordrange.InsertBreak(ref SpecType);//вставляем раздел страницы после каждой таблицы
        //переопределили рандж для исключения перезаписи
        wordapp.Selection.StartOf(ref unit, ref extend);
        wordrange.Collapse(ref direction);//для отчёта схлопываем Range в конец параграфа 
        wordrange.StartOf(ref Story, ref MoveRight);//для отчёта передвигаем левую позицию на одно слово влево
       ////выделил область документа в котором работаем, которая осталась после предыдущего поиска
        wordrange_TEMPLE.Collapse();//для шаблона поиска - схлопываем 
        wordrange_TEMPLE.StartOf(ref Story, ref MoveRight);

        wordrange_TEMPLE.Find.Execute(
            ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj,
            ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj,
            ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj);
    }
    worddocument.SaveAs(ref filename_TOTAL, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj);


}
```

Вертел этот кусок кода и так и сяк, не получается. То диапазон коряво выделяется, то в новый файл информация перезаписывается, а не добавляется в конец. Прошу помощи.

Comment: После достаточно продолжительного (но эпизодического) медитирования над этой темой решил проблему при помощи средств VBA. Макрос получился сравнительно простым, легко изменяемым и работает в разы быстрее, по сравнению с приложением на C#. Для конкретно моей задачи большего желать трудно. Код не привожу, ибо другой язык.